# How can I use Regex to test for these four specific characters? (+ - * /)?

Tags: c#, regex, testing

I have the code to test for a string below, but I am having a difficult time finding documentation for how I would test for these four specific symbols: `+`, `-`, `*`, `/` in my calculator app. Any suggestions are appreciated.

```
if (!Regex.IsMatch(enteredOperation, "^[a-zA-Z]*$"))
{
    Console.WriteLine("Please restart the program and enter one of the symbols + - * / for the operation you want to complete");
    break;
}
```

I also tried the below method, but other characters and numbers are getting past.

```
if (!Regex.IsMatch(enteredOperation, "^(?=.*\\+).{1}$ || ^(?=.*\\-).{1}$ || ^(?=.*\\*).{1}$ || ^(?=.*\\/).{1}$")) 
{
    Console.WriteLine("Please restart the program and enter one of the symbols + - * / for the operation you want to complete");
    break;
}
```

Comment: You want to add any 1 operations among +-/*. Am I right? If yes Does [this](https://regex101.com/r/78UGAg/3) help?

Comment: Yes the user should only be able to type in one of those operation symbols. The link did help. I will have to work with it a bit for it to work.

Comment: Which language or tool you're using. Is it C#?

Comment: Yes I am using C#

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use

```
if (!Regex.IsMatch(enteredOperation, "^[-+/*]$")) 
{
    Console.WriteLine("Please restart the program and enter one of the symbols + - * / for the operation you want to complete");
    break;
}
```

The `^[-+/*]$` pattern matches a string that is equal to `-`, `+`, `/` or `*`.

Comment: Ryszard Czech thanks that works. The program is functioning properly now.